# How to output in the log window in perforce client p4v using custom tools

Tags: python, logging, perforce, customtool

We're developing perforce custom tools in python and we're outputting messages during the script execution. It shows up in p4win but we're mainly using p4v and the output doesn't show up in the log window.

Is there a way to output there or in any other pane without resorting to run the tool in a terminal window?

Answer (score 1):

When Python is directing its output to a pipe rather than straight to a terminal, it buffers its output by default. I think you can work around this by either passing the "-u" parameter when invoking Python (e.g., `python -u myscript.py arg1 arg2`) to tell it not to buffer, or by calling `sys.stdout.flush()` throughout your script any time you want it to make sure that the output has made it to P4V.

See also:

http://kb.perforce.com/article/914/sending-script-output-to-p4vs-custom-tool-terminal

(It looks like that question was asked and answered after you asked here on Stack Overflow. Sorry if you're already well aware of it.)

Comment: I think the issue is the OP wanted to send output to the P4V Log window rather than the custom terminal window. Me too.

Comment: Oh, I see. I'm pretty sure that's not possible. Sorry. My answer is indeed for outputting to what P4V calls a "terminal window". I don't think there's any way to hook into the Log panel.

Comment: Hmm, that's too bad. Pretty sure P4Win supported it. Oh well.